# How Can I Write Scripy To See Url Website?

Tags: python

In Title I Said My Opinion I Wanna See URL After This (?)
For example: this site WWW.name.com has many name after this(?) like these  php?id= 
php?cat=
php?page=
Search in URL and show all things after question mark 
By python3 please

Answer (score 0):

Here try this code:

```
from urlparse import urlparse
rurl = urlparse('http://name.com/data.php?id=5')

query = rurl.query

print query
```

The code above will print the query string which is "id=5"